# Curl and etc. HTTP requests not working when I connected to vpn

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, http, curl

Please tell me how to solve next problem:
Curl and etc. HTTP requests not working when I connected to vpn.
I get a simple error - "could not resolve host".
But when i disconnect from vpn everything works fine

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on Hetzner and Surfshark VPN.

Comment: well, it looks like your missing dns config ... does your vpn modify your /etc/resolv.conf ?

Comment: did you try to install a dns resolver (unbound, powerdns-recursor, bind ) ?

Comment: @dominix no, resolv.conf has not changed, there are only two lines: "nameserver 127.0.0.53" and "options edns0 trust-ad". Just try to install some dns resolver? Or does it need to be configured somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding Google DNS IPs (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) into /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: after hours.. this fixed my problems.. THANK YOU <3